# Как с помощью функции compactMap вытащить определенное значение из словаря в словаре?

Tags: swift, словарь

Есть вот такой словарь в словаре:

```
var dictCityDistance = ["Departure": ["Цюрих": 0], "Destination": ["Цуг": 34]]
```

Как можно вытащить значение ключа "Цуг" с помощью compactMap?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно вытащить

```
let dictCityDistance = ["Departure": ["Цюрих": 0], "Destination": ["Цуг": 34]]
let result = dictCityDistance["Destination"]!.compactMap { Int($1) }
print(result.first ?? 0) // prints 34
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]